# Codeigniter routing and sub routes not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out why when i do sub path for a panel it gives a my page with elements without CSS and sometimes it gives error not showing page.
to be more exactly what i'm trying to do is this scheme:

> Main page
>   Login
>   Admin panel
>   but in admin panel i wanna have subs such as 
>   Admin panel > index
>   Admin panel > config

but when i do the routing like this it gives those problems that i mentioned, for example :

```
$route['admincp/email'] = 'admin/open_email';
```

its not working, but if i do

```
$route['email'] = 'admin/open_email';
```

now it does

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It might be due to other routes you have defined. Maybe if you show all your routes something can be spotted.

Comment: //Main routes
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
$route['login'] = 'main/login';
$route['novidades'] = 'main/news_page';

//Admin routess
$route['admincp'] = 'admin';
$route['logout'] = 'admin/logout';
//Admin config section
$route['emailcfg'] = 'admin/emailconfig';
$route['change_email'] = 'admin/change_email';

Comment: Those routes atm are without the admincp/email_cfg etc, they are just email_cfg because if i add the admincp route before it doesnt work